# Find the real part of function and determine whether it is convex or not.

Tags: complex-analysis, integration

If we have $$g(z)=1+ \int_{0}^{1} \frac {e^{-i\delta}zu^\frac{\alpha}{\beta}}{1-zu} du$$ where $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R},|\delta|\leq \frac {\pi}{2}, z $ is complex and $|z|<1$. How to find the real part of the function $g(z)$ and determine whether it is convex or not?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming $z$ is real. First, we recall the fact,

> A function $f$ is convex on $(a,b)$ iff $f''(x)\geq 0$.

Using the change of variables $t=zu$ we have

$$ g(z)=1+  z e^{-i\delta}\int_{0}^{1}\frac {u^\frac{\alpha}{\beta}}{1-zu} du= 1+  z^{-\frac{\alpha}{\beta}} e^{-i\delta}\int_{0}^{1}\frac {t^\frac{\alpha}{\beta}}{1-t} du. $$

Now, the real part is

$$ u(z)= 1+\cos(\delta)z^{-\frac{\alpha}{\beta}} \int_{0}^{1}\frac {t^\frac{\alpha}{\beta}}{1-t} du$$

which implies

$$u''(z)= \frac{\alpha}{\beta}(\frac{\alpha}{\beta}+1)z^{-2-\frac{\alpha}{\beta}}\cos(\delta)\int_{0}^{1}\frac {t^\frac{\alpha}{\beta}}{1-t} du. $$

From the above, we have

$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac {t^\frac{\alpha}{\beta}}{1-t} du \geq 0,\,\cos(\delta)\geq 0, \, \forall  \,|\delta| \leq  \pi/2. $$

Now, you just need to impose some conditions on $\alpha$ and $\beta$ if possible. So I leave it here for you to finish the task.

Comment: is it true that the real part can be represented as u(z)? Since we know that $Re (wv) \neq Re (w) Re (v)$

Comment: @Norlyda: As I noted in the beginning of my answer, I assumed $z$ is real.

Comment: @Norlyda: Try to work it out for $z$ complex.

Comment: for $z$ real, I already obtained the same answers but it is difficult to find for $z$ complex.

Comment: @Norlyda: Good for you!

Answer (score 0):

Put ${\alpha\over\beta}=:\rho>-1$. Then
$${zu^\rho\over1-zu}=zu^\rho\sum_{k=0}^\infty z^k u^k\qquad(|z u|<1)\ .$$
It follows that
$$\int_0^1 {zu^\rho\over1-zu}\ du=\sum_{k=1}^\infty {z^k\over\rho+k}\qquad(|z|<1)$$
and therefore
$$g(z)=1+e^{-i\delta}\sum_{k=1}^\infty {z^k\over\rho+k}\qquad(|z|<1)\ .$$
As $g$ is an analytic function in $D:\> |z|<1\>$ its real part $u$ is a harmonic function of $x$ and $y$. Now nonconstant harmonic functions cannot be convex, nor concave. This can be seen as follows: In two variables the convexity criterion is that the Hessian should be positive semidefinite. This requires
$$u_{xx}\geq0,\quad u_{xx}u_{yy}-u_{xy}^2\geq0\ .$$
Since for a harmonic $u$ we have $u_{yy}\equiv-u_{xx}$ it follows that the Hessian is indefinite apart from a set of isolated points.

Comment: Is it true if I put it as this $-\frac{r\cos{\delta}}{1+ru} \leq Re {\frac{ze^i\delta}{1-zu}} \leq \frac{r\cos{\delta}}{1-ru}$, $|z| \leq r <1$?

Comment: @Norlyda: This is a new question. I'd say the answer is No.